# Problems in Android Studio & SDK with regards to Drive space

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

new guy here... hope anyone here can help me. I have installed Android Studio in my Drive D. My Drive C is only 128gb and my SDK manager is installed in Drive D. The problem is, when I am updating/installing components in SDK manager, my Drive C also gets affected and I found out that the appdata/local/temp folder is where the files are downloaded. How do I avoid things like this? Any advice/answers? Thanks for help

Comment: go [here](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive) and check if it helps.

Comment: hey thanks for the help, but are you familiar with this? "C:\Users\MYPC\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01" ? That is the one taking up space and I supposed it came from Android SDK Manager components, when Im trying to update and install SDK platforms. How can I avoid that?

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/571901/is-it-safe-to-delete-appdata-local-temp) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/can-i-safely-delete-everything-in-temp/6080f34b-c2c2-4144-9cbd-28d6e04cc0c2).